# parsing xml node with a value and a node inside

Tags: c#, deserialization

We have the following XML

```
<A>
   <B>0
      <C>4</C>
    </B>
</A>
```

As you can see there is a node `C` after the value of node B. We would like to parse it with `Xml.Serialization` tags (`XMLElement`, `XMLRoot`...) as we have done with the rest of the messages.

Any ideas?

Comment: as i know this is incorrect XML...

Comment: I thought that too, but I found out it is correct

Comment: @DmitryMartovoi, What do you mean "incorrect"? This is perfectly valid example of "mixed content" node - you use very similar DOM trees when browsing any HTML page which are essentially all mixed content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such content of nodes called "mixed content".

I never needed to deal with XmlSerialization of such files. Looks like [XmlRootAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltextattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) could be used to serilize such data into list of strings:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
public string[] Text {get;set;}
```